# Does snmp rely on or need CUPS to function?

Tags: cups, snmp

I am trying to secure my latest hosting server, and realized that cupsd is running. After checking, it's running on all of my servers.

In the name of security, I decided to permanently disable this service as I don't have the needs for printing services. Before I do this however, I want to make sure the my SNMP service won't be effected negatively.

Does snmp rely on or need CUPS to function?

Comment: I haven't yet seen an snmp agent that prints; if yours doesn't, I'd think you'd be OK. Ideally, if there really was a dependency, your distribution would link the packages as such.

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for the fast reply. My concern came from this https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/is-cupsd-necesary-on-a-hosting-server.56131/ where they mentioned some services (OS dependant) that relied on CUPS. SNMP was mentioned, thought I would clarify.

Comment: The only mention I can find of either cups or snmp on that page is in list of things that are often installed but often not used.

Comment: @Henrik You are right. I read through this again and see what you are saying. I guess my quest for a quick answer made me read it wrong. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!

I haven't checked but maybe cups can deliver values by snmp, but it certainly doesn't need it.